# Could jumps between floating cities happen in this setting?

Tags: magic, gravity

### Jumps between floating cities.

In this setting floating cities exist because of floating rocks and people already live in them for a long time.

Jumpers, jump between close leveled cities carrying packages. They do it by running in a track and jumping at the end, but, at the moment of the jump someone hands off an object that makes them 95% lighter.

How would that go? Would they be able to make jumps? What perils would they face, like wind gusts and such?

Different objects changing their weight in different percentages would result in longer jumps?

Ps. Jumpers have "winged" suits that help control the trajectory.
Ps2. When landing they would probably release the object and slow their running.

Comment: Ok, gravity is kinda cancelled/reduced, how about inertia? Also - how high are they, what distance - might help. Also what's the sophistication of weather-forecasting there?

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane Not sure. But I would say that it remains the same. But we can change that if the results would be better for the setting.

Comment: Perpetual motion machines aside, if they can reduce their mass arbitrarily, if they don’t have fuels to enable powered aircraft, they should be using man-powered aircraft, or artificial wings: https://xkcd.com/620/

Comment: It would make more sense that they *let go* of something during lift off and *grab onto* something during touch-down - would that be acceptable? Is there a reason why they need to grab onto something (besides the packages) during liftoff?

Comment: Can harpoons and carabiners be a thing?

Comment: @DanielB Man powered aircrafts are a thing the setting has as I want to steer away from steam a bit.

Comment: @cegfault I pictured them running and when jumping receiving the object because I was wondering if having only 5% their actual weight during running would be bad for getting enough speed and actually being blown of course by wind while running.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane Sure. But I would prefer them to be air powered (high pressure canisters) and not use gun powder.  Or even powered by elastic bands like a diver's gun.

Comment: You know, some people think it's tragic when athletes foul up passing the baton at an Olympic relay race.... :)

Comment: @MikeSerfas How did you guess right? That is the exactly image I have in my mind. I thought first to make it a sphere but later decided that a baton would be easier to handle.

Comment: @mcbecker Not entirely relevant for this question, but something to keep in mind - if the baton is made of/filled with antigravity rocks, that means the baton is almost as "heavy" as the person is, pulling upwards.  Holding onto it will be like pulling a 68 kg dumbbell, and their center of gravity will be shifted to the arms.  Jumping with this thing will be less like low-gravity jumping and more like pulling yourself up a rope that isn't fastened to anything, and carrying it will take a great deal of strength.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to better define your world physics to get a reliable answer. Depending on how the hand-held object makes them “lighter” will determine what your dangers are and how dangerous it is. I will “guess” a few options and share the consequences:

## The object Reduces the Jumper’s Mass

If this is the mechanism you use, then you will certainly allow longer jumps, but the jumper’s moment of inertia will become 5% of what it was. Air friction, a slight breeze, and even the position of you hands and legs will make your trajectory completely uncontrollable for any normal human. Think of wrapping a rock in a piece of paper, then throwing it as hard as you can. When the object leaves your hand it has lots of momentum. But when released, the paper falls away. Your jumper will bee like the piece of paper, flitting around chaotically. You will not stay on the same trajectory like the rock does. You are welcome to try this experiment for yourself in a field. So it would boot be recommended to literally make the jumper “lighter” by reducing their mass.

## The Object Reduces Gravity For The Jumper

This presents a more workable solution because your jumper still has all their inertia, and consequently, momentum. It sounds like this was the benefit you were after. The drawback here is that you will loose an ability to control your landing. You will run and jump with normal force and speed, then you will get far more altitude than planned, and fall at a much greater speed than planned; but when you land, your feet will try to stop all that energy with only the friction of a small dog! The effect would be very much like you just throwing a small dog or cat with all your stength, then hoping they land on their own feet alright. Very likely to break some bones this way. Now, with perfect timing, you could have gravity “turn on” at the instant your feet hit the ground. If your jumpers were machines, this would work well. But they aren’t, and they have human reflexes and human reaction times. Their brains will be expecting a certain amount of impact on the landing, then you will surprise it. Your jumpers will need to be extensively trained, like what a professional football player needs. Just this past Superbowl game one of the Bengals tore his ACL tendon with no one near him, he merely placed his foot at a slightly bad angle, the weight of his body was not aligned perfectly, and his ligament got torn. Your brain REALLY needs to be able to predict the forces it is about to react to, and this is all done subconsciously. So jumpers need constant training and conditioning to override their natural instincts.

## The Object Creates an Upward Force

This is similar to turning off gravity but slightly different; it is adding a new force pushing upward. But in this case, you may select what is being pushed upward. Is it the whole jumper? In that case the effect would be identical to reducing gravity. But if you provided lift at the jumper’s shoulders, for example, the jumper would have the sensation like they were strapped into a harness at their shoulders. Or you could have it push only on their feet and they would have to balance on a sort of flying skateboard. There is an infinite number of ways you could manipulate this, and your normal human body would feel mostly comfortable with it because all the normal forces it is conditioned to are still working; it just has to figure out this invisible harness-thing. Another option is that the force only pushes up on their hands, feeling like you are riding a zip-line but it’s impossible to let go or fall because the force is actually your hands. Doing this wrong can risk wrist injuries however, so training is important.

For this option, grabbing the jumper above their center of gravity would be safest and provide the least challenges.

## The Hover-Scooter

Here the object is actually the handlebar of a hovering invisible scooter. This object, when you hold it in a human hand, creates a hard, flat force field 75cm below it. A scooter needs to be pushed every few seconds unless going downhill, but you can’t push off in mid air! So, the jumper gets good speed, grabs the handlebars, and JUMPS off the edge. His feet land solid on a flat force field that projects exactly 75 cm below the bar. It goes all the way around the handlebars like a  frisbee , and also resists air so the jumper can “surf” across the sky. His suit has a tail wing to maneuver; if he needs to steer right, he moves his footing a little to the left and angles the fin in his back.

The force disk repels the ground like a magnet , so on landing, the jumper’s legs don’t feel a big impact; it’s like landing in a sponge.

When he lets go of the bar, the field disappears and the jumper drops to the ground.

Comment: Thank you for exploring all those options. Let me detail how it works and how it fits better with your 3rd option. I pictured a baton filled with crushed dust from floating rocks. The baton would reduce the weight by 95% as a side effect from the crushed rocks. But, I thought also about upward force when reading about buoyancy. The way you describe using zip line is pretty much spot on. Also the baton would have a button to slowly release the costly dust if necessary. But if he jumped like really high he could still land pretty hard right?

Comment: The general problem with a zip-line technique is that it relies on the strength of your hand to stay alive. Watch the Olympic relay race and see why passing a baton often goes badly. So I was hoping this baton grabbed *you* so the jumper can’t accidentally let go; they’re basically being hauled over by the baton. Another problem is direction. What if the jumper kicks slightly left on the jump? He will slowly spin and land facing sideways or backward. Ouch! The winged suit only works if they are horizontal

Answer (score 3):

**Yes - depending on how far they need to jump**

Jumping in a similar setting is already very feasible if they need to jump straight down - the thing called parachute is actually very safe for experienced jumpers.

Jumping horizontally and down is also feasible, although definitely more risky - it is much more easy to crash with a wingsuit rather than with a parachute.

Having an opportunity to lower your weight (or mass) to just 5% changes this calculation. Now it's becoming possible for a human to propel himself/herself on own muscle power, and this power would not even need to me strained. Even distant lateral jumps, as well as jumps up would become possible.

However, if human *mass* is reduced to 5%, there comes an issue of wind. If jumper's entire mass (including cargo) is that low, any strong wing would blow this jumper off course. At high altitudes, high winds are rather common, and it is unclear whether muscle power would be sufficient to compensate for this wind.

I believe that jumping in this setting would be practical and even safe if wind is not an issue, and risky (though still practical) if the wind needs to be accounted for.